# passign a struct pointer to a function and struct padding in c programming

Tags: c, struct, padding

In `build_uart_frame()` , I call `calcFCS()` which calculates an XOR of all the bytes in the struct members(len, cmd0, cmd1 and data).

I do not think the struct is padded therefore will calling `calcFCS()` be an issue? Could somebody explain what is the issue in relation to struct padding as I don't understand its role here and secondly how can I do this operation correctly?

Thank you

```
typedef struct uart_frame {
  uint8_t sof;                    /* 1 byte  */
  uint8_t len;                    /* 1 bytes */
  uint8_t cmd0;                   /* 1 byte  */
  uint8_t cmd1;
  char data[11];         /* 0 -250 byte  */
  unsigned char fcs;              /* 1 byte  */                      
} uart_frame_t;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Global uart frame
   uart_frame_t rdata;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  unsigned char calcFCS(unsigned char *pMsg, unsigned char len) {

  unsigned char result = 0;
  while(len--) { 
    result ^= *pMsg++;
  }

  return(result);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Worker code to populate the frame

int build_uart_frame() {

uart_frame_t *rd = &rdata; //pointer variable 'rd' of type uart_frame    

// common header codes
rd->sof = 0xFE;
rd->len = 11;
rd->cmd0 = 0x22;
rd->cmd0 = 0x05;
snprintf(rd->data, sizeof(rd->data), "%s", "Hello World");
rd->fcs = calcFCS((unsigned char *)rd, sizeof(uart_frame_t) - 1); //issue with struct padding
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unsigned char len` --> `size_t len`

Answer (score 1):

Given your very specific example, it is unlikely that padding will be an issue, since all data types are bytes. Padding is mostly an issue when you use larger data types, because those should typically not be allocated at misaligned addresses.

Yet that is no guarantee: the compiler could in theory decide to replace a `char` with an `int` if it thinks that will get faster code. It is free to insert any amount of padding anywhere in a struct, except at the very top.

This is why structs are unsuitable to describe memory maps or data protocols. You will have to ensure that no padding is present and preferably do so portably. The best way to ensure this is a standard C compile-time assert:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(uart_frame_t) == offsetof(uart_frame_t, fcs)+sizeof(unsigned char), 
               "Padding detected");
```

Here the size of the whole struct is checked against the byte position of the last struct member + the size of that member. If they are the same, there was no padding.

Now of course this only prevents your code from compiling and misbehaving, it doesn't solve the actual problem. Unfortunately there is no portable way to block padding. `#pragma pack(1)` is common but non-standard. `__attribute__((packed))` is another compiler-specific command for this.

Ensuring that no packing is present on the given system where the code is compiled is usually enough.

Also, some of the more exotic systems (MIPS, SPARC etc) don't even support misaligned reads, meaning that misaligned access will not just mean slower code, but a run-time bus error crash.

---

The only way to safely ensure maximum portability of code using structs, is to write serialize/de-serialize routines that manually copies every member to/from a raw byte array:

```
void uart_serialize (const uart_frame_t* frame, uint8_t* raw)
{
  raw[0] = frame->sof;
  raw[1] = frame->len;
  ...
  memcpy(&raw[4], frame->data, 11);
  ...
}
```

The downside of such methods is that they obviously adds some execution time, so I would only use them for code that I know needs to be ported to all kinds of different systems.